# How to use count only on column in EF

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I want to use that query in ef:

```
 select count(number) as CountOfNumber ,number, name  from table_1 group by number, name order by CountOfNumber desc
```

How can I use count on column and add this column new name.

Comment: [How to: Group Query Results - C# Programming Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545971.aspx)

Comment: Along with the problem you should **include the code you have up until this point** (*make some effort to answer your problem/question as Stack Overflow is not a code writing service*). Please also include a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also read [How do I ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: ok i will edit my post :)

Comment: But your comment solved my problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `GroupBy`, `OrderBy` and `Count` combination:

```
var results = (from item in db.table_1
                group item by new { item.name, item.number } into grouping
                orderby grouping.Count() descending
                select new
                {
                    name = grouping.Key.name,
                    number = grouping.Key.number,
                    CountOfNumber = grouping.Count()
                }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545971.aspx

You can use the `Count` method on the group. Where `context` is your Entity Framework data context or any `IEnumerable`.

```
 var results = from t in context.table_1
               group t by new { t.number, t.name } into g
               orderby g.Count() descending
               select new { number = g.Key.number, name = g.Key.name, count = g.Count() };
```